# grub2 cannot detemine new created nvme1n1

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gpt

I add drive `nvme1n1` GPT, add the partition `nvme1n1p1` (ext4)

Here some outputs:

```
lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0          7:0    0 55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2667
loop1          7:1    0 25.1M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/5656
loop2          7:2    0 24.4M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/6312
loop3          7:3    0 55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2654
loop4          7:4    0 49.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17883
nvme0n1      259:0    0   50G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1  259:1    0 49.9G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p14 259:2    0    4M  0 part
└─nvme0n1p15 259:3    0  106M  0 part /boot/efi
nvme1n1      259:4    0    1G  0 disk
└─nvme1n1p1  259:5    0 1023M  0 part

blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="114bf18b-d5bf-4a91-86ea-114248cc92a5" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="bddc87bc-d8f0-4c1e-9c29-8303ca49140e"
/dev/nvme0n1p15: LABEL="UEFI" UUID="AA66-37AB" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="f2a4fc4b-66d2-4596-b582-d4889cbe613f"
/dev/nvme1n1p1: UUID="111ebe2a-f3b8-46a9-adc2-2a416a176ac4" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="01af6b6e-e482-9e43-b22f-a48edf92a2e1"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="33c1fef2-b351-4a2d-a23d-d9fb1e83ba72" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme0n1p14: PARTUUID="98f8d153-cf0a-43c8-9eab-7b95f3039094"
/dev/nvme1n1: PTUUID="d71778c6-5176-1b44-b42e-ca66242d91ab" PTTYPE="gpt"
```

When i restarted, on grub2 menu i try the command (via "c"):

```
grub> ls
(hd0) (hd0,gpt15) (hd0,gpt14) (hd0,gpt1) 
grub>
```

But grub2 can't determine the `(hd1)`.
Why?

Comment: Your blkid is not showing second NVMe drive's partition either, just drive?? What is first partition on it? Or is it corrupted, so cannot be seen?

Comment: dev/nvme1n1p1: UUID="111ebe2a-f3b8-46a9-adc2-2a416a176ac4" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="01af6b6e-e482-9e43-b22f-a48edf92a2e1"

Comment: First find your home directory. After you ls and it shows the list, type `ls (hd0)/home` and then type `ls (hd0,gpt15)/home` and then type  `ls (hd0,gpt14)/home` and then type  `ls (hd0,gpt1)/home` and one of them will return the correct directory then edit your question and let us know.

Comment: Why i should to find the home dir?

Comment: So then I can post a REALY long answer with all the steps to make your machine boot (after we confirm the /boot/grub location because we need that UUID...).

Comment: My PC boots up anyway.
And "home" is located on nvme0n1p1, only what does it have to do with it. I want to install a new system on nvme1n1p1.